# Why Java ImageIcon isn't enter catch clause?

Tags: java, image, try-catch, imageicon

When I try to create ImageIcon, I am getting this error:

```
sun.awt.image.ImageFormatException: Unsupported color conversion request
at sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.readImage(Native Method)
at sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.produceImage(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
```

And if this error occur then I want to load another image so I used try-catch like that:

```
  public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList<?> list, Object value, int index, 
        boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus ) 
{
    // Display the text for this item
    setText(value.toString());

    // Pre-load the graphics images to save time
    String iconurl=ABC.getCiconUrl();
    if(iconurl.isEmpty())
    {
        iconurl="img\\backgroundpic.png";
    }
    try {
        image = new ImageIcon(iconurl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        image = new ImageIcon("img\\backgroundpic.png");
    }
    // Set the correct image
    setIcon( image );
    return this;
}
```

But even the error occur, it is not jumping into catch state. Why ?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1264441

Comment: Are you sure it's the first `ImageIcon` causing the problem?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes I am debugging also, when first ImageIcon, it prints error to console

Comment: I guess the exception is coming from 'catch block'- you have 'new ImageIcon'  in it..  Please show the full code and full stack trace..

Comment: @Jayan I added codes

Comment: First time exception is handled.  When it happens second time you are not handling it..  either you need a try catch in the "catch" or some refactoring ,,

Comment: @Jayan it never jump into catch state, I tried to add try-catch block in 'catch' statement  also in 'try' statement

Comment: Please show the full exception trace.  You are missing some key information in the question-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the stack trace you'll notice that none of your functions is listed in it. The thread throwing the exception is a different one else from the thread that runs your code; it is a thread responsible for asynchronously loading images for ImageIcons, hence you can't catch that exception

Comment: Any suggestions? Attempt to do the same Java code that the ImageIcon stuff does but without using ImageIcon (and renders the image in some GUI component)?

Answer (score 0):

If you load let's say an ImageIO image, you would have to capture IO exceptions like that:

```
  try {
  // The image file is in the java source project \workspace\myproject
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("image.png"));
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

With ImageIcon you can capture exceptions with the Exception Object. You can then load the image with `getResource(path)`. I tried it like this and It worked fine:

```
try {
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("image.png"));
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```